# Validation errors when trying to save image source in database and image in file system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to save an image path in my database and the actual image in the file system. File is copied perfectly but it's source does not get inserted into the database, it's always null in `ModelState.IsValid` function

Here is my movie class

```
public class Movie
{
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int MovieId { get; set; } 

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Genre is required")]
      public string Genre { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Rating is required")]
      public int Rating { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
      public string Description { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Image is required")]
      public string  ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my create view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Movies",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageSource)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            <input type="file" name="uploadImages" multiple="multiple" class="input-files" />

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageSource)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Here is my action method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
{
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                var postedFiles = Request.Files[file];
                postedFiles.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/") + Path.GetFileName(postedFiles.FileName));

            }

            db.Movies.Add(movie);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

`ImageSource` is always null and causing a validation error for one or more entities.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning ImageSource anywhere, either remove ImageSource from the model and use the filename (or fullpath) to write that to the database.

Or use javascript to assign the filename to ImageSource.

Edit: Or just remove the Required attribute from ImageSource.